# ionic/angular html template from a singleton/global class

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, singleton, angular-template

Using Ionic 3/Angular 5, I have a singleton class called Helper containing different functions. It also contains 3 list objects to serve my app (should be used globally).

Now I want to add a `<ion-list *ngFor="let item of itemsList">` but itemsList is in the other/singleton class and not inside the current class. How can I reference it to take the values from the helper class?

For now I added to the .ts of the current class:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private helper: Helper) {
    let itemsList = this.helper.itemsList;
}
```

and it works except it tells me in lint, that itemsList is not used. Actually I have no other use for it except for showing it in the HTML.

I also tried  `<ion-list *ngFor="let item of this.helper.itemsList">` but it didn't work

Thanks

Comment: what if you try :
```currentItemsList:any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private helper: Helper) {
    this.currentItemsList = this.helper.itemsList;
}``` and in html :```<ion-list *ngFor="let item of currentItemsList">```

Comment: i think you defined the itemsList in constructor and the template doesn't know it.

Comment: The template recognizes currentItemsList but I get a lint warning that it is not being used (I use it only for the html template). I want to reference the html template directly to the helper class. If that's possible.

Comment: yes it's possible you can try:```<ion-list *ngFor="let item of helper.itemsList">```

Comment: Works! the problem was private helper: Helper in the constructor, changed it to public and it works! Add it as an answer so I can accept it, thanks!

Comment: even if with private it works but you are right, it's better and correct to make it public, i'll provide as an answer, thank you.

Comment: it didn't work as private for me, it even told me that I access a private element, changed it to public and it worked. Again, thanks a lot

Comment: ```private``` and other access modifiers are Typescript constructs, whereas Component/controller/template are angular constructs that Typescript knows nothing about. Access modifiers control visibility between classes: Making a field private prevents other classes from having access to it, but templates and controllers are things that exist within classes.That's not technically true but Thinking about it that way, obviously we expect private variables on a component class to be visible in its template, for the same reason we expect them to be visible in the private methods on that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like you mentioned,
in component:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public helper: Helper) {}
```

and in template:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of helper.itemsList">
```